# What does nutella add to the Coke+Mentos reaction?

Tags: home-experiment, reactivity

Inspired by [this question on SFF.SE](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/111068/whats-the-nutella-for).

The Diet Coke + Mentos experiment has been a popular one for a while now, and I've [read](http://mentalfloss.com/article/48759/why-do-diet-coke-and-mentos-react) a [little](http://www.eepybird.com/featured-video/coke-and-mentos-featured-video/science-of-coke-mentos/) bit [about](http://www.scientificamerican.com/article/bring-science-home-coke-mentos/) the science behind it.

I recently discovered [this](http://youtu.be/59L51yWUFiQ) video, where an Italian man adds Nutella to the mix<sup>1</sup>, to his great excitement.

However, I'm not clear on *why* he did this; I couldn't see a significant difference in the reaction (although my view was somewhat obscured by the condom). **What does the Nutella add to this reaction?**

---

<sup>1</sup> Do ***not*** watch this video in a public place without headphones on (or the sound turned way down); he gets very, very excited when his <s>abomination</s> experiment (literally) blows up in his face

Comment: Nutella would be very greasy and not dissolve  readily in aqueous solution. I'd speculate that it just makes a bigger mess. // He only added a couple of tablespoons which would have been initially stuck in the neck of the bottle.

Comment: From watching the video I lost 2 minutes of my life. I also think that he just made a non-sense video with Nutella to pormote Nutella or get views for his video from Nutella lovers.  I can find no rationale behind the addition of Nutella.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nutella was used just to protect cola from incidental reaction with Mentos. And it makes more effective insertion - all mentos tabs are inside at the same time.

The reaction is completely the same with [simple Mentos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nf1dFECSf60). (this video also is quite noisy)

This is not chemical reaction, is carbon dioxide evaporation.

Comment: Fair enough; thanks for taking the time to look into this strange, strange question