# Mate & Carbonated water reaction

Tags: organic-chemistry, home-experiment

I know that when adding [carbonated water](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbonated_water) with [Yerba Mate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yerba_mate) leaves there is a reaction that removes the carbonation. (Empirical results)

I wonder what actually causes such reaction but looking in [Scholar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yerba_mate) even for similar reaction such as soda + mate wasn't very productive.

What is the reaction that undergoes there? Is mate just a catalyst ?

Comment: I don't know much about chemistry, but I am trying to come up with an okay question.  At least try to indicate how to improve it rather than just down-voting it.  :(

Comment: The carbonate is supersaturated in solution and unstable. That is why if you just leave a bottle of carbonated water open it will go flat. I'm guessing that the Yerba Mate plant goo has particulates in it which act as nucleating sites for bubbles to form. With a lot of bubbles forming you'll lose the fizz quickly.

Comment: Adding like anything to carbonated water accelerates loss of CO2 http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/42457/what-does-nutella-add-to-the-cokementos-reaction?s=1|1.0737 http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/51167/are-the-ingredients-of-pepsi-in-different-countries-different-enough-to-affect?s=2|1.0200 http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/36977/how-does-the-kreosan-coca-cola-rocket-work?s=4|0.1250